# Calculate forces/ torques on a parallel spring array

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, modeling, springs

I am stuck on the calculation of forces on a certain system involving parallel springs. 
The schematic of the system is as follows:

[image]

The lower plane is fixed and the upper plane movable. There is a symmetric 2x2 matrix of springs between the upper and lower plane. All springs (same size and spring constant) are rigidly attached to the respective planes. The upper plane has a rigid extension (not shown in the image) where forces can be applied such that the upper plane moves/rotates.
In a parallel setup of springs with a symmetric force acting in -z direction I know that I can just add up the spring constants. However what if the force is not parallel to the springs? In  case of a single spring I would model the bending of the spring as beam, but what about a spring array?

Is there a way to compute the forces/ torques acting on the upper plane when I know the relative position (rotation and translation) of the upper plane to the lower plane?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check this out. The problem seems similar. https://study.com/academy/answer/a-rigid-plate-of-side-2a-is-supported-on-four-identical-coli-springs-each-of-stiffens-k-at-the-corners-a-b-c-d-as-shown-in-the-figure-below-a-vertical-force-p-is-now-applied-at-a-point-with-the-coord.html

Comment: Anyone with the solution, feel free to post.

Comment: @Manu G, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer [here](https://study.com/academy/answer/a-rigid-plate-of-side-2a-is-supported-on-four-identical-coli-springs-each-of-stiffens-k-at-the-corners-a-b-c-d-as-shown-in-the-figure-below-a-vertical-force-p-is-now-applied-at-a-point-with-the-coord.html). Feel free to check it out for more details.

[image]

> **Given Data**:
>
> - The stiffness of each spring is k
> - The total force on the plate is P
> - The length of
>      the plate is 2a
> - The coordinate axis are x and y
> - The reaction force on spring A is ${R_A}$
>
> - The reaction force on spring B is ${R_B}$
>
> - The reaction force on spring C is ${R_C}$
>
> - The reaction force on spring D is ${R_D}$
>
> The expression for force equilibrium,
>
> ${R_A} + {R_B} +
> {R_C} + {R_D} = P $
>
> The expression for the moment
>    is
>
> $\begin{align*} {R_A} \times 2a + {R_B} \times 2a - P
>  \times \left( {a - x} \right) &amp;= 0........\left( 1 \right)\\ {R_A}
>  + {R_B} &amp;= \dfrac{{P\left( {a - x} \right)}}{{2a}}........\left( 2 \right)\\ {R_B} \times 2a + {R_C} \times 2a - P \times \left( {y + a}
>  \right) &amp;= 0.......\left( 3 \right)\\ {R_B} + {R_C} &amp;=
>  \dfrac{{P\left( {y + a} \right)}}{{2a}}........\left( 4 \right)
>  \end{align*}$
>
> The expression due to the
>    uniformity,
>
> $\begin{align*} {R_A} + {R_C} &amp;=
>  \dfrac{P}{2}.......\left( 5 \right)\\ {R_B} + {R_D} &amp;=
>  \dfrac{P}{2}.......\left( 6 \right) \end{align*}$
>
> Substituting
>    the value of ${R_C}$ in equation $\left( 3 \right)$ from equation
>    $\left( 5 \right)$
>
> $\begin{align*} {R_B} \times 2a + \left(
>  {\dfrac{P}{2} - {R_A}} \right) \times 2a - P \times \left( {y + a}
>  \right) &amp;= 0\\ {R_B} - {R_A} &amp;=
>  \dfrac{{Py}}{{2a}}.........\left( 7 \right) \end{align*}$
>
> By
>    solving equation $\left( 2 \right)$ and equation $\left( 7 \right) $,
>
> Expression for the reaction force in spring A is
>
> ${R_A} = - \dfrac{{Py}}{{4a}} + \dfrac{{P\left( {a - x}
>  \right)}}{{4a}}........\left( 8 \right)$
>
> Expression for the reaction force in spring B is
>
> ${R_B} =
>  \dfrac{{P\left( {a - x} \right)}}{{4a}} +
>  \dfrac{{Py}}{{4a}}........\left( 9 \right)$
>
> Expression for the
>    reaction force in spring C is
>
> ${R_C} = \dfrac{P}{2} -
>  \dfrac{{Py}}{{4a}} + \dfrac{{P\left( {a - x}
>  \right)}}{{4a}}........\left( 10 \right) $
>
> Expression for the
>    reaction force in spring D is
>
> ${R_D} = \dfrac{P}{2} -
>  \dfrac{{P\left( {a - x} \right)}}{{4a}} +
>  \dfrac{{Py}}{{4a}}........\left( 11 \right)$
>
> Thus equation
>    8,9,10,11 are the expression for the forces in A,B,C,D
>    respectively.